# Serving Large Files Through Nginx via Rails 2.3 Using x-sendfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, mongrel, x-sendfile

Let's say I have a Rails 2.3.2 application fronted by nginx and served by mongrel in which I need to serve a large static file through Rails (to control access to it). I want the Rails app to delegate the transfer of the file to nginx, to avoid blocking the mongrel instance.

The available information seems contradictory and incomplete. [This post](http://www.therailsway.com/2009/2/22/file-downloads-done-right) shows how to do it with Apache, and hints that it can also be done with ngninx - but no examples. [This post](http://john.guen.in/past/2007/4/17/send_files_faster_with_xsendfile/) and [this post](http://spongetech.wordpress.com/2007/11/13/the-complete-nginx-solution-to-sending-flowers-and-files-with-rails/) show how to do it using the a plugin that apparently Rails 2.3 makes uncessary. [This post](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2718-add-nginx-support-for-x_sendfile-option-in-file-streaming) suggests that maybe there isn't support for x-sendfile with nginx after all.

I'd rather not muck around with plugins for things Rails can now do by itself.

Has anybody gotten x-sendfile-like behavior to work using no plugins and Rails 2.3/nginx/mongrel? If not, what's the best documentation for getting it to work with a plugin (and/or monkeypatch) and Rails 2.3/nginx/mongrel?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The main idea: all your controller does is to set the nginx [x-accel-redirect](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxXSendfile) header. Once your controller method returns (which will be very fast), nginx will look at the header your Rails app set. If x-accel-redirect is set, then nginx serves the static file.

Your controller will look something like:

```
def show  
  @attachment = Attachment.find(params[:id])  
  # Do anything else you need for authentication, etc. 

  head(:x_accel_redirect => '/files/' + @attachment.filename,  
   :content_type => @attachment.content_type,  
   :content_disposition => "attachment; filename=\"#{@attachment.filename}\"")  
end
```

This alone won't do the trick. You need to also tell nginx about the files located at $RAILS_ROOT/files. Add this to the end of your nginx config inside the server block:

```
location /files {
  root /path/to/rails_app;  
  internal;  
}
```

Put the static file into $RAILS_ROOT/files and it should work. No need for plugins or monkeypatching Tested with Rails 2.3.2 and 2.3.14.

Comment: Yes that's it.  Notice that que "root" in the nginx conf must be the parent of the location.

Comment: This appears to be a bit old. Is this still applicable for newer versions of rails?