# rails send_file with nginx

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-3, sendfile

I am trying to send a file via send_file, in rails 3... The file is found and is seemingly sent too, but for some reason it is not received...

Also even though :disposition => 'inline' is set, the browser always shows a "download box"...

In nginx conf, sendfile is set to on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, I looked at the response headers and saw the response type was being set as  `application/octet-stream`. Try setting the file's mime type when calling send_file

`send_file file, :disposition => 'inline', :type => 'image/png'`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should go through this: [Serving Large Files Through Nginx via Rails 2.3 Using x-sendfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954470/serving-large-files-through-nginx-via-rails-2-3-using-x-sendfile)