# Message "X-Accel-Mapping header missing" in Nginx error log

Tags: nginx, rack, sendfile, x-sendfile

I am running a Rails 3 site on Ubuntu 8.04 with Nginx 1.0.0 and Passenger 3.0.7.

In my Nginx error.log I started seeing the message `X-Accel-Mapping header missing` quite a lot. Googling lead me to the docs of [`Rack::Sendfile`](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Sendfile.html) and to the [Nginx docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxXSendfile).

Now, my app can be accessed through several domains and I am using `send_file` in my app to deliver some files specific to the domain they are requested from, e.g., if you come to `domain1.com/favicon.ico` I look up the favicon in at `public/websites/domain1/favicon.ico`.
This works fine and I don't think I need/want to get Nginx involved and create some private area where I store those files, as the samples in the [`Rack::Sendfile` docs](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Sendfile.html) suggest.

How can I get rid of the error message?

Comment: Hi @zoopzoop - did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same problem with my rails 3 app hosted on heroku (which uses ngnix).

Comment: Same problem here as well. Passenger 3.0.7, nginx 1.0.0, Ubuntu.

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 15):

this message means that `Rack::Sendfile` disabled `X-Accel-Redirect` for you, because you have missing configuration for it in nginx.conf...

I'm using *Nginx* + *Passenger 3* + *Rails 3.1*.

Gathered information from this pages I've figured it out:

http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel

http://greenlegos.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/sending-files-with-nginx-x-accel-redirect

http://code.google.com/p/substruct/source/browse/trunk/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/sendfile.rb?r=355

[Serving Large Files Through Nginx via Rails 2.3 Using x-sendfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954470/serving-large-files-through-nginx-via-rails-2-3-using-x-sendfile)

I have controller which maps `/download/1` requests to storage files which have their own directory structure, like this: `storage/00/00/1`, `storage/01/0f/15` etc. So I need to pass this through Rails, but then I need to use `send_file` method which will use `X-Accel-Redirect` to send the final file to the browser *through nginx directly*.

Within the code I have this:

```
send_file(
  '/var/www/shared/storage/00/00/01', 
  :disposition => :inline, 
  :filename => @file.name # an absolute path to the file which you want to send
)
```

*I replaced the filename for this example purposes*

Now I had to add these lines to my `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    # ... 

    passenger_set_cgi_param HTTP_X_ACCEL_MAPPING /var/www/shared/storage/=/storage/; 
    passenger_pass_header X-Accel-Redirect;

    location /storage {
      root /var/www/shared;
      internal;
    }

    # ...
}
```

The path `/storage` is not visible from outside world, it is internal only.

`Rack::Sendfile` gets the header `X-Accel-Mapping`, extracts the path from it and replaces `/var/www/shared/storage` with `/storage...`. Then it spits out the modified header:

```
X-Accel-Redirect: /storage/00/00/01
```

which is then processed by *nginx*.

I can see this works correctly as the file is downloaded 100x faster than before and no error is shown in the logs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That sounds great but doesn't really help me since, as I mentioned in my question, I neither have nor want to have one folder with all the files... some are stored in a directory in my Rails app that is shared between deploys, some are being downloaded on the fly from somewhere else and stored in the tmp folder etc. I just want to use send_file without having to set up a separate folder that contains all the files. Possible?

Comment: Yep, in that case you have to create one internal location for every each of them... but I don't know whats the format for X-Accel-Mapping for it... Or, you could maybe add that internal location like "/=/"...

Answer (score 1):

We used the similar technique as **NoICE** described, but i replaced the "hard-coded" directory containing all the files with the regular expression describing *the folder containing the folders containing the files*.

Sounds hard, yeah? Just take a look on these (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/my.web.site`):

```
location /assets/(.+-[a-z0-9]+\.\w+) {
    root /home/user/my.web.site/public/assets/$1;
    internal;
}

location /images/(.+)(\?.*)? {
    root /home/user/my.web.site/public/images/$1;
    internal;
}
```

This should be used with this check:

```
location / {
    # ...

    if (-f $request_filename) {
        expires max;
        break;
    }

    # ...
}
```

to prevent the statics from Rails processing.

Answer (score 0):

I did by this manual

https://mattbrictson.com/accelerated-rails-downloads

my server sends file path `/private_upload/file/123/myfile.txt`, the file is in `/data/myapp-data/private_upload/file/123/myfile.txt`

```
    # Allow NGINX to serve any file in /data/myapp-data/private_upload
    # via a special internal-only location.
    location /private_upload {
      internal;
      alias /data/myapp-data/private_upload;
    }

    # ---------- BACKEND ----------
    location @backend
    {
        limit_req zone=backend_req_limit_per_ip burst=20 nodelay;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header X-Sendfile-Type X-Accel-Redirect;
        proxy_set_header X-Accel-Mapping /=/; # this header is required, it does nothing
        include    /etc/nginx/templates/myapp_proxy.conf;
    }
```